# Swapping the last 2 numbers in a string

Tags: r, string

I have a set of numbers and I wish to swap the last 2, so here my number of 1-10-250-750 will become 1-10-750-250. Obviously this number will change each time so I thought a sub/gsub might do the trick but am unsure how it would be done, or maybe using the 3rd instance of '-' to swap the number before with the number after

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s a solution using regular expressions and replacement patterns:

```
x <- c("1-10-250-750", "1-10-333-444")

sub('(\\d+)-(\\d+)$', '\\2-\\1', x)
# [1] "1-10-750-250" "1-10-444-333"
```

It matches the last two groups of digits and swaps them in the replacement pattern.

Comment: Is there anyway this can be done to use and return a dataframe format?

Answer (score 2):

Split on `"-"`, reverse the last 2 numbers, and `paste` them all back:

```
x <- c("1-10-250-750", "1-10-333-444")

sapply(strsplit(x, split = "-", fixed = TRUE), function(i){
  paste(c(head(i, 2), rev(tail(i, 2))), collapse = "-")
})
# [1] "1-10-750-250" "1-10-444-333"
```

Comment: Is there any way this can take a dataframe format?

Comment: @Joe Yes, `df$newColumn <- sapply(strsplit(df$x, ...`